# How to get object value from NSmutablearray from nested array.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am getting data from SQLite in `NSDictionary` and I am converting into `NSMutableArray`. Now I need to add that array object value in `UITableViewCell` label.

```
arraydata (
    {
    UUID = 995443;
    "group_id" = 41917;
    name = "Maninderveer Kaur";
    "roll_no" = 1;
    "session_token" = bHKkctTPPyULIEy6rh4UKKTO9;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 995445;
    "group_id" = 41917;
    name = "Manjot Kaur";
    "roll_no" = 2;
    "session_token" = bHKkctTPPyULIEy6rh4UKKTO9;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 995447;
    "group_id" = 41917;
    name = "Prabhjot Sharma";
    "roll_no" = 3;
    "session_token" = bHKkctTPPyULIEy6rh4UKKTO9;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 995449;
    "group_id" = 41917;
    name = "Prabhjot Singh";
    "roll_no" = 4;
    "session_token" = bHKkctTPPyULIEy6rh4UKKTO9;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 995451;
    "group_id" = 41917;
    name = "Prince Parbhakar";
    "roll_no" = 5;
    "session_token" = bHKkctTPPyULIEy6rh4UKKTO9;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 995453;
    "group_id" = 41917;
    name = "Puneet Kaur";
    "roll_no" = 6;
    "session_token" = bHKkctTPPyULIEy6rh4UKKTO9;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 995455;
    "group_id" = 41917;
    name = "Rajveer Kaur";
    "roll_no" = 7;
    "session_token" = bHKkctTPPyULIEy6rh4UKKTO9;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 995457;
    "group_id" = 41917;
    name = "Sahajpreet Kaur";
    "roll_no" = 8;
    "session_token" = bHKkctTPPyULIEy6rh4UKKTO9;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 1824273;
    "group_id" = 41933;
    name = Ankit;
    "roll_no" = 1104;
    "session_token" = 9Ea6FqaIKgr9gZ5Gh6UWhVQTj;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 1824271;
    "group_id" = 41933;
    name = Anuj;
    "roll_no" = 1103;
    "session_token" = 9Ea6FqaIKgr9gZ5Gh6UWhVQTj;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
    {
    UUID = 995695;
    "group_id" = 41933;
    name = "Anureet Kaur";
    "roll_no" = 14;
    "session_token" = 9Ea6FqaIKgr9gZ5Gh6UWhVQTj;
    status = present;
    "user_guid" = 995789;
},
  )
```

I have added data on cell ext label by this line.

```
cell.stdntName.text = [array valueForKey:@"name"];
```

I am getting this error when I add a value on cell label:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffcab275550'.

I think above details are OK. Please give some suggestion where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why do you think an array would have a property called `name`?  Do you understand what arrays are?

Comment: sorry sir but i also tried to get vale according to index value

Answer (score 1):

Extract particular dictionary from array according to indexPath and then get value out of that dictionary.

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = array[indexPath.row]
cell.stdntName.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: thats work for me thanks. Sorry for my stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

// try like this

```
if [(array count] > indexpath.row ) {
     cell.stdntName.text = [[array objectAtIndex: indePath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: The range check is a bad idea.  If the array which is the data source mutated without the table view being made aware, it's a programmer bug.  Best to find out ASAP, but letting a runtime exception trigger a crash.

Comment: yes its fine , but how would we know either it(that array) is datasource or not for that tableview.

Comment: If he's pulling data from it to populate a cell, it's the data source.  He could theoretically have a composite data source, but that's overly-complicated, and not nearly as likely.  Obviously, if this data is supplemental, in a use-it-if-it's-there kind of way, one should check if one has it.  That's not the usual case, though.